# Spark 1.3.1 Python ForeachRDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, pyspark

I am writing a script in python which takes an RDD from a kafka Dstream. I then want to take the RDD break it down and perform a hive query among other things.
To do this I am using the following piece of code

```
recommendationDataset = parsedStream.map(lambda (v): (v.get("CustomerId"))).foreachRDD(generateRecommendation)
```

I then call a hive query from within generateRecommendation.
Is it possible to perform a hive query in this command somehow without having to call foreachrdd and then a function? I'm knew to spark and python.

```
        def generateRecommendation(avroCustomer):
           print "=========================Generate Recommend========================="
           from pyspark import SparkContext,SparkConf
           from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

           print(type(avroCustomer))
           newAvroCustomer = avroCustomer.collect()
           for x in newAvroCustomer:
              print "===Query DB==="
              CustomerPurchaseHistorySingle=sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM CustomerPurchaseHistoryAllRec WHERE CustomerId=%s" % x)
              CustomerPurchaseHistorySingle.show()
              print(type(CustomerPurchaseHistorySingle))
              print(type(CustomerPurchaseHistoryAllRec))


           print "=======================Generated Recommend!========================"
```

Comment: I doubt you are running hive query. Can you show us generateRecommendation? I think you are just creating a hive sql context and running your sql there.

Comment: Yeah i create the CustomerPurchaseHistoryAllRec from hive up front at the start of the app, and then I access it from within this function so I guess its just a spark sql query. I still don't understand how I can perform this query from within a lamda as oppossed to within a function. Also I don't quite understand how to pass multiple parameters into generateRecommendation since it does not like to take any paramterers when you call it from foreachrdd()

Comment: I think you better take a look in design patter for foreachRDD. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#output-operations-on-dstreams. I think the way you are doing is not the most optimal way.